# How to track Mobile site video events in Google Analytics?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, video, google-analytics

In our desktop site we're including MP4 videos with mediaelement js player. We're currently tracking video events using Google Analytics plugin but we're confused how this will work with our jQuery mobile site, because In mobile when we click on a video it will load on a native video player application instead of playing through mediaelement js player?

If our videos played on native application are we unable to track Google Analytics events on the video ?

Could anyone please let me know how can we overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I've not used it specifically for tracking video this script - https://code.google.com/p/google-analytics-js/ - has been very helpful in tracking 3rd party usage of a JS library.

In the same way that I'm calling it within the JS library you could hook a call to `gaTrack('UA-123456', 'yoursite.com', '/assets/videoname.mp4');` into where you launch the video in jQuery.

Note that this will only let you track the launch, you'll be limited in which events you can track when it's running in the native player (some are better than others in feeding pause/seek etc events back to the player but you'd need to test that something like https://gist.github.com/Offbeatmammal/3718414)

Essentially what the script does is manually construct a call to the GA tracking gif with correct parameters. You could also construct your own virtual push for virtual pageviews but that requires a bit more work https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncMigrationExamples#VirtualPageviews

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer partially correct however when experiment this situation with my test files. It's all working as normal even though mobile device opening the videos in separate native player GA still able to track the events on the player.

Comment: which device/OS are you using? On Nexus it seemed to behave well, but some Samsung (for instance) there seemed to be a bunch of events missed... but glad that it is working (hopefully every release adds better support)